# How to write microsoft event log in asp.net core 1.1?

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to write Microsoft event log in my application using Asp.net core 1.1. I have searched and got the extension "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog". But I am unable to install on my application due to compatibility.
Is there any other possible solution to achieve event log in asp.net core 1.1?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog` in version `1.1.2`. If you tried to install in now, it might have tried to install 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

The compatibility problem you hit likely appears because you attempted to install the `2.0.0` version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog` for your ASP.NET Core 1.1 application.

In preparation for the final release of ASP.NET Core 2.0, it appears that the NuGet packages were [published early](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2125), which makes those the newest stable versions on NuGet causing the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio to pick those by default.

You have to be careful with which versions you pick when installing dependencies for ASP.NET Core. Especially soon, when 2.0 releases, you have to make sure to always pick the latest 1.x release for as long as you stay on ASP.NET Core 1.x.

In your case, you need version [1.1.2 of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog/1.1.2) which is the latest 1.x version for the dependency. So either pick that in the NuGet package manager, or change your `.csproj` to include the proper version:

```
<PackageReference Name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="1.1.2" />
```

Comment: Unable to install version 1.1.2 also. It is showing the error while installing in Nuget manager. 
Error: Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for application.

Comment: Did you try manually adjusting your `.csproj` for this? Use `dotnet restore` from the command line afterwards.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have updated the version in .csproj.